# dplyr: Filter based on a vector

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I assume the error is in the code and therefore I think this example is enough.

I wanted to filter my df (df2) according to the vector i created. This vector was created extracting information from a column of another data frame (df1).

Vector based on df1: (extracting the 3rd column of df1)

```
 vector_df1 <- df1 [, 3]
```

Trying to apply filter on df2, based on the vector_df1

```
Filter_df2 <- df2 %>%
                    
               filter(Column_df2 %in% vector_df1)
```

Results: 0 rows

Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: So you have a vector i.e. `df1[,3]` or a tibbble try `vector_df1 <- df1[[3]]` if it is a tibble

Comment: Also, please check if the `filter` is from `dplyr` i.e. `dplyr::filter` instead of some other package filter

Comment: @akrun it works. Can you tell me where can i see the difference between a tibble or a vector

Comment: I posted with the documentation.  Please check in the solution . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of structure of dataset i.e. with `data.frame`, if we use `[,col]`, it uses `drop = TRUE` and coerces it to `vector`, while for `data.table` or `tibble`, by default, it is `drop = FALSE`, thus returning the tibble itself with single column. The documentation can be found in `?Extract`.  Safe option is `[[` which have the same behavior in extraction of column as a `vector`

```
vector_df1 <- df[[3]]
```

---

According to `?Extract`, the default usage is

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

and it is specified as

> or matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

The documentation for `tibble` can be found in `?"tbl_df-class"`

> df[, j] returns a tibble; it does not automatically extract the column inside. df[, j, drop = FALSE] is the default. Read more in subsetting.